# How to find the Jacobian for implicit functions?

Tags: partial-derivative

I have to find the Jacobian for $$\begin{align}
u&= x/ (1-r^2)^{1/2}\\ 
v&= y/ (1-r^2)^{1/2}\\   
w &= z/ ( 1-r^2)
\end{align}$$
where $r^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$
 but I am not able to solve it without making it more complicated. I think that maybe it can be done by using implicit functions but maybe I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that when you say Jacobian, you want the matrix

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial u}{\partial z} \\
\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial v}{\partial z} \\
\frac{\partial w}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial w}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial w}{\partial z}
\end{bmatrix}.$$

If so, then you can find the partial derivative using a combination of the Quotient Rule,
$$\frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{f}{g }\right) = \frac{f^\prime g - f g^\prime}{g^2}$$
and the Chain Rule
$$ \frac{d}{dx} \left(f(g(x)) \right) = f^\prime (g(x)) g^\prime (x).$$
Let me know if you need more direction!

Answer (score 0):

You're right about using implicit differentiation, but it's only a minor part of it.  I'll use $u_x$ to mean ${\partial u\over\partial x}$ and similar notation for other partial derivatives.

We have $$u={x\over(1-r^2)^{1/2}}$$

By the quotient rule, $$
\begin{align}
u_x &= {(1-r^2)^{1/2}-x\left(\frac12\right)(1-r^2)^{-1/2}(-2r)r_x\over1-r^2}\\
&={(1-r^2)+xrr_x\over(1-r^2)^{3/2}}\\
\end{align}
$$
Implicitly differentiating $r^2=x^2+y^2+z^2$ with respect to $x$, we have $rr_x=x,$ so that $$u_x=1-y^2-z^2$$

Similarly, $$\begin{align}
u_y &= {-x\left(\frac12\right)(1-r^2)^{-1/2}(-2r)r_y\over1-r^2}\\
&={xrr_y\over(1-r^2)^{3/2}}\\
&={xy\over(1-r^2)^{3/2}}
\end{align}$$

Similar formulas hold for all the other partial derivatives.

When you say "Jacobian" I'm not sure if you mean the Jacobian determinant or the Jacobian matrix.  The matrix is just $${1\over(1-r^2)^{3/2}}\begin{bmatrix}
1-y^2-z^2&xy&xz\\
xy&1-x^2-z^2&yz\\
xz&yz&1-x^2-y^2
\end{bmatrix}$$